# Bash SVN Post Commit Hook

Tags: bash, svn, trac

I have a working post-commit hook bash script that syncronises a Trac instance with the latest revision for an SVN commit.

```
#!/bin/sh

TRAC="/var/trac/"

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

if [[ "$REPOS" = "*TechReader*"]]; then trac-admin $TRAC"techreader" changeset added $REPOS $REV; fi
if [[ "$REPOS" = "*InteractEnglish*"]]; then trac-admin $TRAC"interactenglish" changeset added $REPOS $REV; fi

trac-admin $TRAC"egloo" changeset added $REPOS $REV
```

The final `trac-admin` call runs and updates the internal Trac instance as desired but the if statements don't seem to fire the updates for our client instances of Trac.

The commands to sync are the same so is something wrong with the conditions?

Answer (score 2):

With some tinkering, I was able to get this to execute correctly. Note that I replaced your `trac-admin` calls with simple `echo`s for testing.

```
#!/bin/bash

TRAC="/var/trac/"

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

if [[ "$REPOS" == *TechReader* ]]; then echo "first IF" $REPOS $REV; fi
if [[ "$REPOS" == *InteractEnglish* ]]; then echo "second IF" $REPOS $REV; fi

echo "done";
```

Changes I made

- change bin/sh to bin/bash
- add a space before ]]
- remove quotes around the second arguments